# UIImage custom Init tint color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

#### Description:

I am writing an extension for `UIImage` which should initialize a system image with a given custom type of `SystemImage`.

Everything works well except that the image tint color is not as I have configured in *Storyboard* for the `UIImageView` tint color.

This only occurs when using the custom init and calling `self.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)`.

When I access the image directly (`UIImage.SystemImage.bolt_circle_fill.image`) I get the image with the correct tint color.

- Image is showing **correctly** - `UIImage.SystemImage.bolt_circle_fill.image`
- Image is showing **incorrectly** with a Black tint color - `UIImage(systemImage: .b_circle_fill)`

Any assistance will be appreciated.

#### Code:

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    
    convenience init(systemImage: SystemImage) {
        
        let image = systemImage.image
        
        self.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
    }
    
    enum SystemImage: String {
        
        case bolt_circle_fill
        case b_circle_fill
        case icloud_circle_fill
        case flag_circle_fill
        case play_circle_fill
        case heart_circle_fill
        case f_cursive_circle_fill
        
        var image: UIImage {
            
            let imageName = self.rawValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: ".")
            let image = UIImage(systemName: imageName) ?? UIImage()
            
            return image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try refactoring your code so that you get a "systemName" from the enum and you call `self.init(systemName:)` in your convenience initializer.